# aggregate by week of daily column

Tags: python, pandas

Hello guys i want to aggregate(sum) to by week. Lets notice that the column date is per day.
Does anyone knwos how to do?

Thank you
kindly,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-01','2021-01-02',
                   '2021-01-03','2021-01-04','2021-01-05',
                   '2021-01-06','2021-01-07','2021-01-08',
                   '2021-01-09'],
               'revenue':[5,3,2,
                          10,12,2,
                          1,0,6]})
    

df

    date        revenue     
0   2021-01-01    5           
1   2021-01-02    3           
2   2021-01-03    2           
3   2021-01-04   10          
4   2021-01-05   12          
5   2021-01-06    2           
6   2021-01-07    1           
7   2021-01-08    0           
8   2021-01-09    6
```

Expected output:

```
2021-01-04.    31
```

Comment: why it is negatively rated  ? What is missing please

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with aggregate `sum`, but is necessary change default close to `left` with `label` parameter:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


df1 = df.resample('W-Mon', on='date', closed='left', label='left').sum()
print (df1)

            revenue
date               
2020-12-28       10
2021-01-04       31
```

Comment: thank you for your response!! My sample was wrrong ! Iupdated my answer please have a look. Thank you

Comment: yes == 10+12+6+0+1+2. week 04/01/2021 = (04/01/2021, 05/01/2021, 06/01/2021, 07/01/2021, 08/01/2021, 09/01/2021. Please tell me if im not clear. I want to do like date_trunc in sql.

Comment: @nepe - understand, changed answer.